# Sylius cache management

Tags: symfony, caching, e-commerce, sylius

When I started to use Sylius I did not realize that it is not stable yet and I fully customized the **dev** version instead of starting a new project. Now, I think that I can't put it in **prod** because of cache management :

- Images do not always load but sometimes :

  `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html`
- Same for CSS and JS :

  `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

And I can't clear the cache with `php app/console cache:clear -e prod` :

```
Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug true
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 98304 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\sylius\app\cache\pro_\twig\9a\2e\9cb2d88c764cb674efaa179d7259f64ff3b6396785924a758ca5728914b5.php on line 98

PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\sylius\app\console:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() C:\wamp\www\sylius\app\console:28
PHP   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:121
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:96
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:191
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:905
PHP   7. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->execute() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:244
PHP   8. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->warmup() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand.php:83
PHP   9. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate->warmUp() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand.php:120
PHP  10. Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\CacheWarmer\TemplateCacheCacheWarmer->warmUp() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate.php:47
PHP  11. Twig_Environment->loadTemplate() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\CacheWarmer\TemplateCacheCacheWarmer.php:62

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 98304 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\sylius\app\cache\pro_\twig\9a\2e\9cb2d88c764cb674efaa179d7259f64ff3b6396785924a758ca5728914b5.php on line 98

Call Stack:
    0.0005     331032   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\sylius\app\console:0
    0.0698    3608112   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() C:\wamp\www\sylius\app\console:28
    0.0764    3860448   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:121
    0.6014   15730344   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:96
    0.6027   15730344   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:191
    0.6034   15755448   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:905
    0.6037   15755792   7. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->execute() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:244
    0.7519   16165176   8. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->warmup() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand.php:83
    7.0263   57502064   9. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate->warmUp() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand.php:120
   14.6093   95010368  10. Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\CacheWarmer\TemplateCacheCacheWarmer->warmUp() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate.php:47
   21.6284  133900880  11. Twig_Environment->loadTemplate() C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\CacheWarmer\TemplateCacheCacheWarmer.php:62
```

EDIT : I already cleared the cache manually but it didn't change anything.

Comment: You could try running `$ rm -rf app/cache/*` to see if that helps

Comment: depends what you're using to run the commands. Cygwin or Git Bash will execute that rm command. You could also just delete all the files in the app/cache directory with the Windows Explorer

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I **already tried  to clear it** manually.

Comment: Do you even read the error messages? they are really clear, php is configured with too little memory_limit

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`#!/user/local/bin/php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

The answer is based on symfony documention:

https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/console/usage.html